# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error for -timeIntervalSinceNow

Tags: ios, nsdate

Hoping someone can help with this. I keep getting a bad access error when trying to use the `-timeIntervalSinceNow` method. I have a variable in this class called `NSDate *startDate` and I've added `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *startDate;`

`startDate` is used in the code here:

```
    startDate = [NSDate date];
    updateTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 
                                                   target:self
                                                 selector:@selector(updatePlaybackPosition:)
                                                 userInfo:nil
                                                  repeats:YES];
}
```

}

```
- (void)updatePlaybackPosition:(NSTimer *)timer {
   NSTimeInterval interval = [startDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
```

When the program reaches  `[startDate timeIntervalSinceNow]` it gives a bad access error. From the other posts I've read on this topic, the answer usually seems to have something to do with retaining the date. So, I'm not sure what I'm missing. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Your `NSDate` was auto released before the timer fired. **updated:** Make sure you use the property that you declared instead of the instance variable by using `self.`. That will handle the retaining for you properly.

```
self.startDate = [NSDate date];
```

and then

```
- (void)updatePlaybackPosition:(NSTimer *)timer {
   NSTimeInterval interval = [self.startDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
```

Comment: I missed your property declaration in the post. You are not accessing the the property but the instance variable. I will update my answer.

Comment: Oh thanks, that makes sense. I've made the change, still same thing though.. loops through the update timer once and then bad access on that line..

Comment: Thanks very much for your thoughts, any further ideas about it please do post

Comment: Look through your code for any calls to release on startDate other than dealloc, only other thing I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured out the answer to this, in the end. It seems like its better to use

```
-timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate date]
```

rather than using -timeIntervalSinceNow. It essentially does the same thing, but for some reason -timeIntervalSinceNow gives a bad access error every time, but the method above works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

`[NSDate date]` returns you an autoreleased `NSDate`. If you want to use that value outside of the method where it was returned to you, you have to `retain` it (and `release` it when you're done with it).

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to [[NSDate date] retain] and that stops the program from giving a bad access error the first few times [startDate timeIntervalSinceNow] repeats in the timer, however, it still gives a bad access after a few loops through. Also, the time interval it returns is null. Any further suggestions?